# Line of credit for investment

Tags: united-states, investing, mortgage, investment-property

My house value increased in the past 3 years, is it possible to use that to obtain a line of credit (currently i have 1 single mortgage) and convert this to cash/use it as a downpayment so i can invest it in a second property?

Comment: Can you edit and add country tag

Comment: Yes, but your debt to income ratio must be high enough to qualify, typically that means: monthly debt payments / monthly gross income < 0.43. They'd include your HELOC and new mortgage in that calculation. I'd argue it's not a great idea, but many people do it without issue.

Comment: This is known as a start of a bubble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is called a Home Equity Line of Credit (HELOC). While the strategy you are describing is not impossible it would raise the amount of debt in your name and reduce your borrowing potential. A recent HELOC used to finance the down payment on a second property risks sending a signal of bad financial position to credit analysts and may further reduce your chances to obtain the credit approval.